# Missing jboss-modules.jar in jboss 7.2

Tags: eclipse, jboss, redhat

i try to open add-user.bat in jboss v7.2 but i receive this error

```
 WARNING: The JBOSS_HOME ("C:\Users\PC\Ep\bin") that this script uses points to a different installation than the one that this script resides in ("C:\Users\PC\Ep"). Unpredictable results may occur.

      JBOSS_HOME: "C:\Users\PC\Ep\bin"

Could not locate "C:\Users\PC\Ep\bin\jboss-modules.jar".
Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.
```

I find this in eclipse :

```
 The home directory is missing a required file or folder: C:/Users/PC/Ep/bin/jboss-modules.jar
```

Any idea to solve this problem? 
I need link to download jboss-modules.jar relative to jboss red hat 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable looks wrong. It should be set to `C:\Users\PC\Ep\`. The `bin` directory should not be in the environment variable.